# SSH port forwarding occasionally fails

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

I'm using SSH port forwarding to get to a DB behind a firewall. I use the following command (forwards remote 5432 port to local 5430):

```
ssh -i privatekey -v -N -A \
ec2-user@host -fNT -4 -L \
5430:rds-endpoint.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
```

This command always returns exit code 0, but approx. once in ten cases it doesn't actually open the tunnel and I get *connection refused* error when I try to connect to `localhost:5430`.
I've checked the debug output and noticed that there's one difference. The **unsuccessful** runs' debug output ends with this:

```
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
```

while the **successful** runs have 3 more lines after the `forking to background` line:

```
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

So I assume SSH fails to "enter interactive session". Is there a way to fight this bug and make the port forwarding command reliable?

Comment: Hello and welcome! I there any chance that a previous session is still alive on the port when this occurs? As far as I can see this is the most common reason this error occurs.

Comment: @g_bor hi! This command is run in a CI job, only once per a dedicated VM. I saw this error happening when there were no parallel jobs running. I assume the CI provider (CircleCI) kills all processes after the job finishes, so I never cared to close the connection myself.